# WPF drag and drop: need a big flat drop target

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement a very simple application where you drop a file anywhere in the client area and it gets converted. Here's my XAML:

```
<Grid AllowDrop="True">
  <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    Drop .dds files here and they will be converted to .png files in their original directory
  </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

However, when I do this the only allowable drop target is the `<TextBlock>`, not the rest of the big flat white space. When I put a file over any area where there's not text, I get a "no" cursor and the drop event does not get triggered.

How can I bend WPF to my will? Why is it doing this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why, but if you set AllowDrop="True" on the parent of the grid it works as expected.

Comment: The grid is my root element... what did you do that made it work?

Comment: Oh I see, if I set `AllowDrop="True"` on the `<Window />` element it does what I want...